# Pass System.currentTimeMillis() as parameter between test steps in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

We have a test Suite containing 3 steps. The first step executes a WSDL. The second is a delay of 10 seconds and the third calls another WSDL.

The first requires the `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a parameter. The same time needs to be passed to the third. We have tried setting a run time parameter like `${=System.currentTimeMillis()}`.

This works fine for the first step. But when the third step is called, the `${=System.currentTimeMillis()}` is executed again giving a different millisecond value. Is there any way how we can get the current milli second in the first step and pass the same across the third?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a property to your test case, called "currentTimeMilisecond". Then, add a groovy test step, before your other requests, like this:

```
context.testCase.properties["currentTimeMilisecond"].
    setValue(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
```

Then, in the test steps replace your ${=System.currentTimeMillis()} with ${#TestCase#currentTimeMilisecond}.

This seems to work for me, but I don't know your specific requests. 
Good luck!

Comment: Sorry about the last answer, cut-and-pasted me silly. This example should work.